# SQL first_value and last_value

Tags: sql, netezza, window-functions

This is Netezza, which runs a flavor of Postgres

I'm using the `first_value` and `last_value` window functions, which are giving different values and confusing me.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
select
    a.emp_id
    , a.sequence
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence) AS first_dept
    , LAST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence) AS last_dept
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence) AS first_seq
    , LAST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence) AS last_seq
FROM
    tname a
WHERE
    1=1
    AND a.event_id IN (1, 2)
    AND a.emp_id=11111
```

For `emp_id = 1111` this returns 2 records.

```
emp_id   SEQuence   FIRST_DEPT  LAST_DEPT   FIRST_SEQ   LAST_SEQ
90565520    1       200800      200800      1           1
90565520    10      200800      200932      1           10
```

I'm confused as to why `last_seq` is returning `1` instead of 10

Answer (score 3):

In the window functions `order by` used for "running" calculations, so for first row `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` returns values for first row only and for second row it returns values for two rows and so on.

You can ensure in it by adding something like `sum(a.sequence) over (PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence)`. In your example it will be 1 and 11 (= 1+10).

So you should to remove `order by` from `over` and add `order by a.DEP_ID, a.sequence` at the end of the whole query.

Comment: Do you know of a way to filter down the results to just 1 record per `emp_id`? I got the query to return the right values for `first_seq` and `last_seq` from your suggestion, but now need to return just 1 of those records

Comment: @simplycoding "just 1 of those records" is not well formulated condition :) You can use your original query as subquery and then filter it's results. Like `select * from (<your_original_query_here>) t where sequence = last_seq` for example will return only last rows for each `emp_id` (if `sequence` is unique for `emp_id`).

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
create table sample (id int, val int);
insert into sample select i, i from generate_series(1,5) i;
```

When you use `order by` in a window function it calculates cumulative values:

```
select 
    id, val,
    first_value(val) over (order by val),
    last_value(val) over (order by val),
    sum(val) over (order by val)
from sample;

 id | val | first_value | last_value | sum 
----+-----+-------------+------------+-----
  1 |   1 |           1 |          1 |   1
  2 |   2 |           1 |          2 |   3
  3 |   3 |           1 |          3 |   6
  4 |   4 |           1 |          4 |  10
  5 |   5 |           1 |          5 |  15
(5 rows)
```

Just do not use `order by`:

```
select 
    id, val,
    first_value(val) over (),
    last_value(val) over (),
    sum(val) over ()
from sample;

 id | val | first_value | last_value | sum 
----+-----+-------------+------------+-----
  1 |   1 |           1 |          5 |  15
  2 |   2 |           1 |          5 |  15
  3 |   3 |           1 |          5 |  15
  4 |   4 |           1 |          5 |  15
  5 |   5 |           1 |          5 |  15
(5 rows)
```

To get exactly one row you can use `DISTINCT ON`. Add `ORDER BY sequence desc` so the last seuqence will be shown in the row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.emp_id)
    a.emp_id
    , a.sequence
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id) AS first_dept
    , LAST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id) AS last_dept
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id) AS first_seq
    , LAST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id) AS last_seq
FROM
    tname a
WHERE
    1=1
    AND a.event_id IN (1, 2)
    AND a.emp_id=11111
ORDER BY
    a.sequence desc;
```

Comment: Result set is returning multiple records, normally 2 records per id like what I put in the original post. This is not unexpected. Any way to limit this to the last record returned?

Comment: Does that work on Netezza? I don't see support for `DISTINCT ON (colname)`. I ended up doing just `DISTINCT colname, colname2`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Adding the statement "rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following" solved it. Your amended code would look something like this:

```
select
    a.emp_id
    , a.sequence
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence)     AS first_dept
    , LAST_VALUE(a.DEP_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS last_dept
    , FIRST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY     a.sequence) AS first_seq
    , LAST_VALUE(a.sequence) OVER(PARTITION BY a.emp_id ORDER BY a.sequence     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS last_seq
FROM
    tname a
WHERE
    1=1
    AND a.event_id IN (1, 2)
    AND a.emp_id=11111
```